# Betweenness preserving implies monotonic?

Tags: real-analysis, examples-counterexamples, order-theory, monotone-functions

For this question, we can assume that $f:\mathbb{R}\rightarrow\mathbb{R}$. However, I hope that an answer can generalize to arbitrary linearly ordered sets.

I assume that everyone will know what I mean by $f$ being weakly increasing, weakly decreasing, or monotonic. However, now let me introduce a different notion:

> Let me say that for three real numbers $x$, $y$, and $z$ that $y$ ***lies between*** $x$ and $z$ if either of the compound inequalities below hold
>   $$x\leq y\leq z\quad\text{or}\quad z\leq y\leq x\,.$$
>
> Let me say also that $f$ ***preserves betweenness*** if whenever $y$ lies between $x$ and $z$ then $f(y)$ lies between $f(x)$ and $f(z)$.

Of course, a monotonic function preserves betweenness.

But the question is:

> If a function preserves betweenness is it necessary monotonic? I.e., must it either be weakly increasing or weakly decreasing?

It seems like it should be, but then I recall Darboux functions and become hesitant to jump to this conclusion. If a betweenness-preserving non-monotonic function exists, it would be kind of odd.

It's readily apparent that it cannot have any strict local extrema. Also, if it has a local extremum at $x$, then there will be $a$ and $b$ such that $a<x<b$ where $f$ is constant on either $(a,x]$ or $[x,b)$ or both. However, any other properties that we investigate seem to require an intractable number of case analyses.

I'm reminded of some ghastly functions like those that satisfy the Cauchy functional equation but are not continuous anywhere. But those functions are unbounded on every interval.

Comment: Note that this is false for partially ordered sets, where you can have incomparable $a,b$ both $<c$ and map this betweenness preservingly but not monotonically to $[3]=\{1<2<3\}$ via $a\mapsto 1$, $b\mapsto 3$, $c\mapsto 2$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, betweenness-preserving implies monotonic.

Suppose $f$ is not monotonic, then there exist $a<b$, $f(a)<f(b)$, and also $c<d$, $f(c)>f(d)$. We note that $f$ is still not monotonic on $F:=\{a,b,c,d\}\subset\mathbb R$. Let's write $F$ as $F=\{a_1<a_2<\dots<a_k\}$ where clearly $k\in\{3, 4\}$.

Choose $i$ minimal such that $f(a_i)\ne f(a_{i+1})$.

Case 1: $f(a_i)<f(a_{i+1})$. Then there must be $j\ge i+1$ with $f(a_j)>f(a_{j+1})$, or else $f$ is weakly increasing on $F$. Then for the minimal such $j$ we are done: $f(a_i)<f(a_j)>f(a_{j+1})$ and $f(a_j)$ is not between $f(a_i)$ and $f(a_{j+1})$, so $f$ is not betweenness-preserving.

Case 2 is the same.

Comment: This is sleeker and clearly covers each case.

Comment: Thanks @RobertWolfe yes it avoids the issue of whether $a_2=d$ and $a_3=b$ and... the ghastly number of cases!

Answer (score 1):

Suppose that f is not monotonic. Then $\exists x, k$ s.t. $x < k$ and $f(x) < f(k)$ *and* $\exists x_0, k_0$ s.t. $x_0 < k_0$ and $f(x_0) > f(k_0)$.

WLOG, let $k < x_0$. Then we get a contradiction on $f$ preserving boundedness because either $f(k)$ or $f(x_0)$ will not lie between $f(x)$ and $f(k_0)$.

Comment: I think there's a typo here. But I can redraw the pictures that I think you had in mind. How do you eliminate the possibility that $f(k)=f(x_0)$? In this set of circumstances. But I also have an issue with the "without a loss of generality" part. How about the possibilities of $x<x_0<k<k_0$? or $x_0<x<k_0<k$?

Comment: @RobertWolfe You're right, there is a small typo. It should say $f(x) < f(k)$ in the first line. Does that help?

Comment: @RobertWolfe The WLOG just allows us to consider the nice ordering $x < k < x_0 < k_0$. Other cases are similar: consider the two 'endpoints' and then one of the two points in between will give a contradiction. The proof above is not entirely rigorous, you're correct.

Comment: I think the last $f(k)$ should be $f(k_0)$. I'm running through cases.

Comment: @RobertWolfe. Ah, yes, right again.

Comment: @RobertWolfe If that's the case then there is a contradiction on preserving betweenness because $f(x_0)$ and $f(k)$ are not in between $f(x)$ and $f(k_0)$. In your definition of _preserves betweenness_ x is $x$, z is $k_0$, and y is either $x_0$ or $k$.

Comment: Suppose $f:X\to Y$ where $X$ and $Y$ are linearly ordered sets. Some trivial observations: (1) If $f$ is not weakly increasing, then there is a $2$-element set $X_0\subseteq X$ such that the restriction of $f$ to $x_0$ is not weakly increasing. (2) The same goes for weakly decreasing. (3) If $X$ is not monotonic, then there is a set $X_0\subseteq X$, with at most $4$ elements, such that the restriction of $f$ to $X_0$ is not monotonic.

Comment: I saw that. I'm still running through cases, but I think this argument is solid. But there's a ghastly number of cases that one has to check. Maybe not ghastly. But a number that's irritating.

Comment: (4) Therefore, in order to prove that betweenness-preserving implies monotonic for mappings between arbitrary linearly ordered sete, it suffices to consider cases where domain and codomain have at most $4$ elements. So, nothing about the real line, no set-theoretic pathology involved, just simple combinatorics.

Comment: I now believe this argument is essentially correct. Following @bof comment's, and employing a little metaphor, the graph of such a function will either have a mountain peak, a valley, or an acute trapezoid in it. All of which don't preserve betweenness. I doubt the argument will get better for arbitrary ordered sets.